# sharepoint- creating a new web application

Tags: sharepoint, web-applications

i have sharepoint (wss 3.0) installed. I would like to create a new web application but instead of using the default templates (team site, blank site, etc.) i would like to use a custom template. Basically, I want to copy a site that I have created (copy as site template) and use it in another web application.

How do i accomplish this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

On the site you want to copy, go to '**Site Actions**' and pick '**Site Settings**'. From there, you can pick '**Save site as template**' under the '**Look and Feel**' section.

When you're creating a new site, there should be a new tab on the Templates box called '**Custom**' - simply select your template, and away you go! Make sure that if you're deploying on another server, you'll have to install any custom web parts as well (BEFORE you create the site). The same applies for custom lists - templates can be saved from the List Settings page.

If you're going to be setting this site up in an entirely different Site Collection, you simply have to save the templates to your local system and upload them to the appropriate template galleries on the new Site Collection.

Comment: i know how to create the template but HOW do i use it in a NEW web application? ie: from configuration manager under application management and create or extend a new web application?

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, if you want to start a new web application and use one of your custom templates as the root template you can upload your STP file to the global template gallery.

See the [stsadm -o addtemplate](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287945.aspx) command